# Cual es la IP de mi servidor centos en virtualbox

Tags: web, apache, servidor, centos

Actualmente estoy configurando mi servidor centOS 7 en un virtualbox para usarlo como servidor web de pruebas, como soy nuevo en esto me gustaría saber cual es la ip por donde esta corriendo el servidor apache y poder acceder a el desde el navegador

Les dejo una imagen cuando he ingresado el cmd **ip addr**

[image: ip addr cmd]

Comment: Prueba desde la consola de _virtualbox_ con `ifconfig`. Debería de salir la configuración de red. La por defecto _eth0_ es la de acceso.

Comment: Si no te aparece es porque la interfaz de red no está activada. Tal vez esto te ayude: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36705/why-the-default-eth0-interface-is-down-by-default-on-centos?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa